# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') . It runs completely fine few hours ago when i come back It throws this error

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Nitems from "./Nitems";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import './Font.css'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


export class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps={
    country: "in",
    category: "general"
  }
  static propTypes={
    country: PropTypes.string,
    category: PropTypes.string
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("Hii this is a constructor");
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      page: 1,
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setProgress(10)
    let url =
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=${this.props.apikey}&pagesize=12`;
    this.setState({loading: true})
    let data = await fetch(url);
    this.props.setProgress(30)
    let parsedata = await data.json();
    this.props.setProgress(70)
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedata.articles,
      totalarticles: parsedata.totalResults,
      loading: false
    });
    this.props.setProgress(100)
  }
  previouspage = async () => {
    this.props.setProgress(10)
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}$apiKey=${this.props.apikey}&page=${
      this.state.page - 1
    }&pagesize=12`;
    this.setState({loading: true})
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedata = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedata);
    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page - 1,
      articles: parsedata.articles,
      loading: false
    });
    this.props.setProgress(100)
  };
  
  nextpage = async () => {
    this.props.setProgress(10)
    if (this.state.page + 1 > Math.ceil(this.state.totalarticles / 12)) {
      
    } 
    else {
      let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=${this.props.apikey}&page=${
        this.state.page + 1
      }&pagesize=12`;
      
      this.setState({loading: true})
      let data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedata = await data.json();
      console.log(parsedata);
      this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        articles: parsedata.articles,
        loading: false
      });
      this.props.setProgress(100)
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container ">
        <h3 className="my-3" className="text-center" style={{margin: "18px 0px", fontFamily:" Permanent Marker", fontSize: "45px"}}>Top Headlines </h3>
        {this.state.loading && <Loading/>}
        <div className="row">
          {!this.state.loading && this.state.articles.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                <Nitems
                  title={element.title.slice(0, 50)}
                  description={
                    element.description
                      ? element.description.slice(0, 45)
                      : "Description is not available. The ADP"
                  }
                  img={element.urlToImage}
                  nurl={element.url}
                  date={element.publishedAt}
                  author={element.source.name}
                ></Nitems>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button
            disabled={this.state.page <= 1}
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            onClick={this.previouspage}
          >
             Previous
          </button>
          <button disabled={(this.state.page + 1 > Math.ceil(this.state.totalarticles / 12))} type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.nextpage}>
            Next 
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

It runs completely fine few hours ago when i come back It throws this error. The render section remains unchange. Can you please check this out what is wrong with this code.
I think it is a API regarding error. Because when i whenever i trying to pass my api key through the props this error will come. I saved the api key into a .env.loacl file.
Can you please check this out what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the following > `articles: [],loading: false,`

Notices that your only verifications is if `!this.state.loading` then try to map over `articles`, but since ur `loading` starts as false it will pass ur conditiong, and then ur `articles` didnt have mounted yet, since it starts **empty []**, so it tries to map over an empty array and react will throw that error.

One way to fix that is to >> `!this.state.loading && this.state.articles.length > 0 && ...proceed to map`

With this you will be doubling check if articles has been populated and when it has values in it, he will automaticly starts reendering.